# git pull -v: up to date but isn't

Tags: git

I want to know if my branches are synced with the remote:

```
git pull -v
From ...
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
 = [up to date]      release    -> origin/release
```

I read the above output like: OK, release branch is up to date.

But `git diff release origin/release` shows that there are differences.

Is the output of `git pull -v` correct?

Comment: What is the full output of `git pull -v`? And what are the differences (the output of `git diff ...`)?

Comment: @AD7six I have 201 lines... I cut it to show the important part. I added the master branch to make it more pleasant to human eyes, but AFAIK this does not mater in this context.

Answer (score 4):

`git pull` does two things: `fetch` and `merge`.

The above output ("up to date") means: The `fetch` is up to date. But attention: the merge was not done yet.

With `git branch -av` you get a better output:

```
git branch -av
  release                4fa0a21 [behind 6] changed version from 2014.10 to 2014.11 in setup.py
  remotes/origin/release 4011230 changed version from 2014.12 to 2014.13 in setup.py
```